# NetBeans: How to automatically convert if-else if statement to switch?

Tags: java, netbeans

The question is simple: I wanted to convert if-else statement into switch with a shortcut or accessing from the menu in Netbeans.

Sometimes it does not appears on the caution signal to change from there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the Hint "Replace chain of ifs with switch" in the options dialog:

[image]

Once that is enabled you will, get a little yellow light bulb next to all if statements that qualify for that:

[image]

If you click on the light bulb you get the option to convert the ifs to a switch:

[image]

And then the code will be changed to:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes that options does not appears :(

Comment: @LorenzoLerate: what is the "minimum branch count" setting? And if it is configured as "Warning on current line" it will only appear when you put the cursor on the of the `if` statements.